# getting callback is not a function when my function does have a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

I do not understand why I keep getting the error message: uncaught type error: callback is not a function. I clearly have a callback function in my giveTrack function. Any insight?

```
function giveTrack(track, elementid) {
    SC.oEmbed(track, {
        auto_play: false,
        maxheight: 125,
        maxwidth: 300
    }, document.getElementById(elementid), function(oEmbed) {
        console.log(oEmbed.html);
    });

}


var looper = 0;
for (x in djlist) {
    SC.get('/users/' + djlist[x] + '/tracks', function(tracks) {
        console.log(tracks[0]);
        myTrack = tracks[0].permalink_url;
        var g = document.createElement('div');
        g.id = "hello" + looper;
        document.createElement('br');
        giveTrack(myTrack, "hello" + looper);

        looper++;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SC.oEmbed` method takes either an element:

```
SC.oEmbed(url, options, element);
```

or a callback:

```
SC.oEmbed(url, options, callback);
```

You are trying to use both an element and a callback. The method will ignore the fourth parameter, and try to determine the type of the third parameter.

You have created an element with a specific id, but you haven't added that element to the page. When you use `getElementById` to find the element, you will get `null` back.

Because the third parameter is `null`, the method can't determine if it's supposed to be an element or a callback, so apparently it assumes a callback. As the reference is `null`, it can't be used as a function.

Ref: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#embedding

Comment: How do I add the element to the page before I call SC.oEmbed

Comment: @user2510809: You would use the `appendChild` method (or similar) to add it to an element in the page.